# Find first monday date of month

Tags: javascript

I have a date (usually the first day of a month but not necessary, it could be any date) and I want a new date corresponding to the first Monday of that month.

example:

```js
findFirstMonday('1 jul 2021') -> 7 jul 2021
findFirstMonday('1 aug 2021') -> 2 aug 2021
findFirstMonday('13 aug 2021') -> 2 aug 2021
```

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```js
const selectedDate = new Date();

const daysInSelectedDate = daysInMonth(selectedDate);
const lastDayPreviousMonth = addDays(selectedDate, daysInSelectedDate - selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
const firstDayPreviousMonth = removeDays(
  lastDayPreviousMonth,
  daysInMonth(lastDayPreviousMonth),
);
console.log('firstDayPreviousMonth: ', firstDayPreviousMonth);
let firstMonday = firstDayPreviousMonth;
while (firstDayPreviousMonth.getDay() !== 1) {
  console.log('firstMonday: ', firstMonday, firstMonday.getDay());
  firstMonday.setDate(firstMonday.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log('firstMonday: ', firstMonday, firstMonday.getDay());

function addDays(date, days) {
  const result = new Date(date)
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days)
  return result
}

function removeDays(date, days) {
  const result = new Date(date)
  result.setDate(result.getDate() - days)
  return result
}

function daysInMonth(date) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate()
}
```

What am I wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The first Monday in July is the 5th, not the 7th, so your code is actually correct for the test case. I'm not sure if your code is actually wrong.

Comment: Last line of your result `2021-07-05T10:11:26.200Z"` is correct answer. The first Monday of  July the 5th. So the `findFirstMonday('1 jul 2021') -> 7 jul 2021` must be `findFirstMonday('1 jul 2021') -> 5 jul 2021`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

```js
    console.log(findFirstMondayMonth('1 jul 2021').toLocaleDateString())
    console.log(findFirstMondayMonth('1 aug 2021').toLocaleDateString())
    console.log(findFirstMondayMonth('2 aug 2021').toLocaleDateString())
    console.log(findFirstMondayMonth('13 aug 2021').toLocaleDateString())

    function findFirstMonday(dateString) {
      let date = new Date(dateString)
      let diffDay = date.getDay() - 1
      if (diffDay == -1) {
        diffDay = 6
      }
      let mondayDate = new Date(dateString);
      mondayDate.setHours(mondayDate.getHours() - diffDay*24)
      return mondayDate
    }
    
    function findFirstMondayMonth(dateString) {
      let date = new Date(dateString)
      if (date.getMonth() == findFirstMonday(date).getMonth()) {
        let dateOneWeekBefore = new Date(dateString)
        dateOneWeekBefore.setHours(dateOneWeekBefore.getHours() - 24 * 7)
        if (date.getMonth() == dateOneWeekBefore.getMonth()) {
          return findFirstMondayMonth(dateOneWeekBefore)
        } else {
          return findFirstMonday(date)
        }
        
      } else {
        let dateOneWeekAfter = new Date(dateString)
        dateOneWeekAfter.setHours(dateOneWeekAfter.getHours() + 24 * 7)
        return findFirstMonday(dateOneWeekAfter)
      }
    }
```

Sorry for the last answer, I think it was the first monday of week and I don't see Sunday.getMonth() == -1

Comment: This does actually not work at all (for the specified use case): 1. given a Sunday it will return the _previous_ Monday; 2. it does not return the _first Monday of a month_ but the next/previous; 3. the returned date may be not even in the same month

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following code. Some explanations about the general idea:

1. For a given date get the first date in the month of the given date. This is quite easy by generating a new Date object with `day = 1` and the year and month of the given date.
2. Get the weekday of the first date.
3. Depending on the weekday of the first date, you must calculate which day number the first Monday has. This number is calculated by `((8 - firstWeekdayInMonth) % 7)`. You can easily verify yourself, that this always yields a Monday. The modulo is important for Sundays and Mondays, where you would otherwise add 8 and 7 respectively, which would not yield the first Monday anymore.

```js
console.log(findFirstMonday('1 jul 21'))
console.log(findFirstMonday('1 aug 21'))
console.log(findFirstMonday('13 aug 21'))

function findFirstMonday(dateString) {
  let targetDate = new Date(dateString);
  let targetMonth = targetDate.getMonth();
  let targetYear = targetDate.getFullYear();
  let firstDateInMonth = new Date(targetYear, targetMonth, 1);
  let firstWeekdayInMonth = firstDateInMonth.getDay();
  let firstMondayDate = 1 + ((8 - firstWeekdayInMonth) % 7);
  return new Date(targetYear, targetMonth, firstMondayDate).toLocaleDateString();
}
```